# How can I change the background color from yellow to red depending on a percentage?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, frontend

I am developing a polling website in which the poll option progress changes color depending on the percentage of votes. Currently, the color changes using an if statement that checks on the progress percentage. Is there a better way to do this without relying on this many if statements? Like a gradient of some sort? I would be okay with both vanilla and jQuery solutions.

```
function progressColor(progress) {
    if (progress >= 0 && progress <= 24) return '#FFE169';
    else if (progress >= 25 && progress <= 49) return '#FFDE59';
    else if (progress >= 50 && progress <= 74) return '#FF914D';
    else if (progress >= 75 && progress <= 89) return '#FF7A7A';
    else if (progress >= 90 && progress <= 100) return '#FF5757';
}
```

Comment: I'd do this with CSS classes instead of direct manipulation of the color. Anyway, since this looks like a yellow-orange color scale, you could probably do it with parametric HSL colors too?

Answer (score 1):

Here's an approximate parametrization of your color scale.

You can use the slider to change the background color too.

```js
function progressColorPara(progress) {
  const progressP = progress / 100;
  const hue = 48 * (1 - progressP);
  const lightness = 71 - 11 * progressP;
  return `hsl(${hue},100%,${lightness}%)`;
}

for(let i = 0; i < 100; i+=10) {
  const div = document.createElement("div");
  div.style.backgroundColor = progressColorPara(i);
  div.innerText = i;
  document.body.appendChild(div);
}

document.getElementById("p").addEventListener(
  "input",
  e => document.body.style.backgroundColor = progressColorPara(e.target.valueAsNumber),
);
```

```css
div {
  padding: 0.5em;
}
input {
width: 100%
}
```

```html
<input type="range" min=0 max=100 step=0.1 id=p />
```

Answer (score 1):

Same function, use math.
Base color:
0xFFE169
final color 0xFF5757
and between them...0xFFE169 - 0xFF5757 = 8a12
so:
every percentage is in hex ~ 162 = (DEC)354

```
function progressColor(progress) {
    if(progress == 0) return 'FFE169';
      else {
          return (Number("0x"+"FFE169") - (354 * progress)).toString(16);
             }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To a computer, colour is just a bunch of numbers. That means, in theory, you could do some maths to get the number that's a certain percentage point difference between a lower and higher number. With your scale, I don't think it's as simple as that however we'll keep the essence of the idea and get some help with a library which does all the complex maths: [**chroma.js**](https://gka.github.io/chroma.js/).

chroma.js has a function called [`scale`](https://gka.github.io/chroma.js/#chroma-scale) which can take an array of colours that appear on the scale. Using the colours in your question, you would build a scale like this:

```
const scale = chroma.scale(["#FFE169", "#FFDE59", "#FF914D", "#FF7A7A", "#FF5757"]);
```

`scale` returns a function which you can call with a percentage to get the colour at that percentage on the scale.

```
scale(0); // #FFE169
scale(0.25); // #FFDE59
scale(0.5); // #FF914D
scale(0.75); // #FF7A7A
scale(1); // #FF5757
```

Below is a demo, constructing a scale from the colours in your question and using inputs to change the percentage and get a specific colour on the scale.

```js
const initialValue = 0;
const number = document.getElementById("number");
const range = document.getElementById("range");
const output = document.getElementById("output");
const scale = chroma.scale(["#FFE169", "#FFDE59", "#FF914D", "#FF7A7A", "#FF5757"]);

number.value = initialValue;
range.value = initialValue;

const initialColor = scale(initialValue * 0.01).toString();
output.style.backgroundColor = initialColor;
output.textContent = initialColor;

function updateColor(percentage) {
  const color = scale(event.target.value * 0.01).toString();
  output.style.backgroundColor = color;
  output.textContent = color;
}

number.addEventListener("change", ({ target: { value } }) => {
  range.value = value;
  updateColor(value);
});

range.addEventListener("input", ({ target: { value } }) => {
  number.value = value;
  updateColor(value)
});
```

```css
body {
  font-family: monospace;
}

#range {
  width: 100%;
}

#output {
  align-content: center;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: bold;
  height: 50vh;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100vw;
}
```

```html
<input id="number" type="number" min="0" max="100" />
<input id="range" type="range" min="0" max="100" />
<output id="output"></output>
<script crossorigin src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chroma-js/2.4.2/chroma.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Personally, and I appreciate I'm deviating from your specified colour-scheme, I'd approach this as follows (explanatory comments are in the code below):

```js
// using document.querySelector() to retrieve the first element on the page that
// matches the supplied CSS selector (this returns null if no element is found,
// in production please use sanity-checks to guard against errors of that kind:
let input = document.querySelector('input'),
    // this is the name of the event we're using to set/updated the CSS custom
    // properties:
        evtName = 'input';

// here we use EventTarget.addEventListener() to bind the anonymous function of
// the method as the event-handler for the named - 'input' - event:
input.addEventListener(evtName, (evt)=>{

  // from the Event Object - passed in automatically - we retrieve the
  // element to which the event-listener was bound (the <input>):
    let changed = evt.currentTarget;
  
  // from the <input> we navigate up through the parent elements to find the
  // first <main> element, and use CSSStyleDeclaration.setProperty() to
  // set the custom property (indicated by the '--' notation) that's equal
  // to the <input> element's 'name' attribute, setting that property to
  // the value of the <input> element:
    changed.closest('main').style.setProperty(`--${changed.name}`, `${changed.value}%`);
  
  // from the <input> we find the first ancestor <label>, and from there
  // we use Element.querySelector() to find the <output> element contained
  // within; we then set its textContent property - using a template-literal String
  // (as above) - to be equal to the value of the <input>, followed by the '%' sign:
  changed.closest('label').querySelector('output').textContent = `${changed.value}%`;
});

// here we use EventTarget.dispatchEvent() to trigger the named event ('input')
// on the <input> element, causing the event-listener to run, and initialise
// the state according to the starting value(s):
input.dispatchEvent(new Event(evtName));
```

```css
:root {
  --main-inline-size: 80%;
  --main-max-inline-size: 1200px;
  --main-min-inline-size: 20rem;
  --spacing: 0.5rem;
}

*,
::before,
::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font: inherit;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  block-size: 100vh;
  font-family: system-ui;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 400;
  padding: var(--spacing);
}

main {
  /* here we set the background-color of the <main> element, using the color-mix() function;
     first we set (and this is required) the color-space in which the colors should be mixed,
     here I use the 'oklab' color-space; we then mix the end-color using the var() function
     at a percentage equivalent to the "progress"; that way zero progress results in zero
     of the end-color, and 100% progress results in 100% percent of the end-color.
     These CSS custom properties are set via JavaScript, but handled by CSS: */
  background-color: color-mix(in oklab, var(--end) var(--progress), var(--start));
  border: 1px solid currentColor;
  inline-size: clamp(var(--main-min-inline-size), var(--main-inline-size), var(--main-max-inline-size));
  margin-inline: auto;
  min-block-size: 100%;
  padding: var(--spacing);
}

form {
  /* backdrop-filter is used to differentiate the background of the <form> and to have
     the various form-elements stand out, by rotating the hue of the ancestor's background
     by 15degrees, and increasing the brightness by 75% (if we set the brightness filter
     to 100% then we'd have the same brightness as the ancestor's background): */
  backdrop-filter: hue-rotate(15deg) brightness(175%);
  border: 1px solid currentColor;
  border-radius: 0.5rem;
  inline-size: fit-content;
  margin-block: 0.5rem;
  margin-inline: auto;
  padding: 1rem;
}

label {
  display: flex;
  gap: 1rem;
  padding: 0.5rem;
}

output {
  inline-size: 5rem;
}
```

```html
<!--
  using the "style" attribute to define the initial CSS custom properties, one of which
  - --progress - will be updated later with JavaScript:
-->
<main style="--start: #FFE169; --end: #FF5757; --progress: 0%;">
  <form action="#" method="post">
    <legend>Simulate progress:</legend>
    <label>
      <span class="labelText">Progress</span>
      <input type="range" name="progress" min="0" max="100" step="0.1" value="0" id="progress">
      <output for="progress"></output>
    </label>
  </form>
</main>
```

[JS Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/c9ov7wsy/).

References:

- CSS:

  - [`backdrop-filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/backdrop-filter).
  - [`block-size`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/block-size).
  - [`calc()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc).
  - [CSS custom properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/--*).
  - [`inline-size`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/inline-size).
  - [Filters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter):

    - [`brightness()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter-function/brightness).
    - [`hue-rotate()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter-function/hue-rotate).
  - [`mix-blend-mode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/mix-blend-mode).
  - [`var()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/var).
- JavaScript:

  - [Arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions).
  - [`closest()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest).
  - [`CSSStyleDeclaration.setProperty()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleDeclaration/setProperty).
  - [`document.querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector).
  - [`Element.querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/queryselector).
  - [`Event()` constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/Event).
  - [`EventTarget.addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener).
  - [`EventTarget.dispatchEvent()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/dispatchEvent).
  - [Template-literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals).